# Cannot convert argument 1 from 'float *' to 'CArray &'

Tags: c++, arrays, fft, valarray

I'm trying to apply FFT ([this rosettacode.org C++ implementation of FFT](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform#C.2B.2B) :     `void fft(CArray &x) { ... }`, or should I use the [C implementation](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform#C) ?) to an array given by this data :

```
float *x
VstInt32 sampleFrames    // basically the length of the array
```

When I do:

```
fft(x);
```

I get :

```
error C2664: 'void fft(CArray &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'float *' to 'CArray &'
```

How to solve this kind of error?

---

Comment: Where's the rest of the code? You've shown the error but not the code that caused the error

Comment: Sorry @EdChum, you're right. I added :     `void fft(CArray &x) { ... }`   and I call it with `fft(x);`

Comment: why would you expect this to work? In the link it's `typedef`ed as `typedef std::valarray<Complex> CArray;` which clearly is not a `float*`

Comment: So sorry @EdChum, I'm trying to recode my DSP algo (which works great in Python) in C++, but my C++ memories are a bit far... Should I turn the valarray into a `float*` ?

Comment: I think you need to take a step back and try to get the sample code, either of them, to compile first and then adapt it to your needs currently you seem to be very far away from your solution as you're experiencing syntax  errors so you should start with something that works and then modify it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to convert array to CArray type alias:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/20adde65619732f8

```
typedef std::complex<double> Complex;
typedef std::valarray<Complex> CArray;

void fft(CArray& x)
{   
}

int main()
{
    float sx[] = {1,2,3,4};

    float *x = sx;
    int sampleFrames = sizeof(sx)/sizeof(sx[0]);

    // Convert array of floats to CArray
    CArray ca;
    ca.resize(sampleFrames);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sampleFrames; ++i)
      ca[i] = x[i];

    // Make call
    fft(ca);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This does a copy of the array into a new `CArray`. Isn't there a way to make a CArray from a `float *` in place, without copying ?

Comment: I dont think so, the problem is that your source data is of type float and you need to convert it to complex<double>, even C - version would require copying. You can find all valarray constructors here : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/valarray

Comment: True, thanks @MarcinJędrzejewski. This makes me think I need rfft anyway (real FFT like here : http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.rfft.html)